# SSH and ufw from multiple ip addresses

Tags: server, ssh, ufw

[image: ufw commands]

I'm interested in setting up some basic security on an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS that I'm working on. I'm reading through these articles:

- [My First 10 Minutes On a Server - Primer for Securing Ubuntu | Codelitt Incubator](https://www.codelitt.com/blog/my-first-10-minutes-on-a-server-primer-for-securing-ubuntu/)
- [My First 5 Minutes On A Server or Essential Security for Linux Servers | Bryan Kennedy's Blog](http://plusbryan.com/my-first-5-minutes-on-a-server-or-essential-security-for-linux-servers).

I'm reading the section about ufw now. I'm going to be connecting from variable IP addresses via ssh. Given this requirement, what should I set the first line in the screenshot to, to make sure I retain access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about the title, but to answer your question

> I'm going to be connecting from variable ip addresses via ssh. Given this requirement what should I set the first line in the screenshot to, to make sure I retain access?

`sudo ufw allow 22` or even `sudo ufw allow OpenSSH` will open up port 22 to the world.

I didn't look at your links, but I hope they also suggest using keys instead of password login.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend installing DenyHosts and Fail2Ban as well as using UFW. What you can do is go into DenyHosts and whitelist a range of IPs. For instance I have 192.168.1.* White listed so any connection from local is allowed. I also have my work IP white listed as well.

DenyHosts can be installed with `sudo apt-get install denyhosts`. Then go into `sudo nano /etc/denyhosts.conf` and configure your SSH.

You will need to go into `/var/lib/denyhosts` and either create or add to the `allowed-hosts` file.
http://www.sgvulcan.com/2010/03/26/whitelist-a-host-when-using-denyhosts/

See also this for more in depth security see the following link: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1604-lts-server-part-1-basics